# How to get only one user instead of a list?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I try to get from a list of users to only one user and display his profile on another page.

I want to do so with the routerLink and passing on an id of this specific user to the next page.

The routing is working, Im directed to the profile page but when I log the results of the http request I still get back the whole list of users like in the users page instead of the details of one user.

I have tried many things like changing the path of the url in my user.service.ts but that didn't solve the problem I even got 404 request errors when using this path `${this.url}/users/${id}/` instead of `${this.url}/users/?i=${id}/` (where its working).

The api docs is saying though that in order to retrieve one single user its `http://1234//users/{id}/` it this scheme while id is an integer. But when I want to apply that scheme I get the 404 error.

Thats why I have to use the `?I=` version but there the problem is I only get the full list of users on the next page.

MY CODE:

user.service.ts

```
// get a user's profile
  getUserDetails(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users/?i=${id}/`); // why add ?i
  }
```

user.page.ts

```
// get all users in the users page
  getAllUsers() {
    this.userList = this.userService.getList()
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
  }
```

user.page.html

```
   <ion-avatar  class="user-image"  slot="start" [routerLink]="['/','profile', 'user.id']">
            <ion-img src="assets/22.jpeg"> </ion-img>
     </ion-avatar>
```

profile.page.ts

```
 information = null;
...
  ngOnInit() {
     // Get the ID that was passed with the URL
     let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

     // Get the information from the API
     this.userService.getUserDetails(id).subscribe(result => {
       this.information = result;
       console.log(result);
     });
   }
```

Comment: I assume ${this.url}/users/?i=${id} will get you the list of the users, because the params might not even matter, so it's basically the same as ${this.url}/users/. You said the docs mentioned that to get a single person the url should be ${this.url}/users/${id}. I would suggest to find out why you get an error when you use that url

Comment: long shot, just to be sure: it does say `/users/{id}` and not `/user/` ?

Comment: no its saying `/users/{id}`

Comment: @rtpHarry I think I know the problem. Since id has to be a number. How would I have to change `let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');` so its taking a number?

Comment: its not a number once its turned into a query string, so it doesn't make any  difference in this case. You can use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you really want to though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the url is wrong. If it was me I would console.log the url and compare it to the docs. Heres a snippet to try a few variations:

```
    const id = 1;

    const options = [
      `${this.url}/users/?i=${id}/`,
      `${this.url}/users/?i=${id}`,
      `${this.url}/users/i/${id}/`,
      `${this.url}/users/i/${id}`,
      `${this.url}/user/?i=${id}/`,
      `${this.url}/user/?i=${id}`,
      `${this.url}/user/i/${id}/`,
      `${this.url}/user/i/${id}`,
    ];

    for (const option of options) {
      try {
        const response = await this.http.get(option);
        console.log(options, response);
      } catch (e) {

      }
    }
```

I would also consider dropping the second http request. If the first request returns all the required data you could just store it in a variable on the service.